# Why my D3.js Dropdown filter is random ?

Tags: javascript, json, d3.js, drop-down-menu, filter

I've build the following table here :

https://bl.ocks.org/simonbreton/d4d2ea338d1bacc6ce3d0a295529bcb4

However as you can see if you try to select different option, data doesn't update correctly. [image]

Some doesn't show up (here in the picture batman for example) and others doesn't remove. For exemple in the picture again, I've expected to remove superman, captain and Antman for seeing only batman data.

What's wrong with my code ?

thanks a lot !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By default d3 identifies data by index in the array. It doesn't play well with filtering - some elements get dropped and it changes the indexes of succeeding elements. Adding a [key function](https://bost.ocks.org/mike/constancy/#key-functions) to your data binding could help, however, there is also a problem with your dataset. It contains duplicates and there is no property that could distinguish them. If names were unique you could use a key function like below:

```
var rows = tbody.selectAll("tr")
                .data(filterdata, function (d) { return d.name})
```

Comment: OK Lukasz. Thanks a lot. I've update my dataset with different strength value for each name. I guess I can use the following code like you suggest :
`var rows = tbody.selectAll("tr")
      .data(filterdata, function (d) { return d.linkclicks});`

but if I understand well there is no day to deal with duplicates row ?

Comment: You're welcome Simon. I don't see `linkclicks` in your dataset but when you use `strength` as a key now then it should show multiple rows for the same name. See my jsfiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/LukaszWiktor/006xwa8j/

Comment: Yeah thanks. it's working fine now. however could you explain me in more details the difference between simple .data(mydata) and .data(mydata, something else). I understand why do I have to do this but I don't really understand what happen within D3.... ?

Comment: The simple `.data(mydata)` works this way: 
1. you select "superman", there are 4 supermans in your dataset, so after filtering they land in a 4-elements array with indexes 0,1,2,3 - d3 appends 4 rows, 
2. you select "spiderman" - there is only one in the dataset, after filtering it becomes a 1-element array with index 0, 3d identifies that elements 1,2,3 are gone and removes related rows from the table, "superman" 0 remains 
3. you select "captain", there are 3 of them, so the dataset after filtering has 3-elements, d3 checks that element 0 is already present so it appends only 1 and 2

Comment: 4. you select "ironman", there are 2, d3 removes 3rd row, rows associated with indexes 0 and 1 remain in the table - 3d thinks that they are the 2 ironmans but you see "superman" and "captain"
5. and so on... I guess you catch that

Comment: Now the second case - if you provide a key function - the second parameter to `.data(mydata, something else)` then you tell d3 how to distinguish existing elements from incoming or outgoing ones. d3 can now notice that "superman" differs from "spiderman" because they have different strength so it needs to remove all "supermans" from the table and append "spiderman". Here is also the thing why you need a unique property. If all "supermans" have the same strength then d3 thinks that they are all the same and appends only 1 row.

Comment: Ok thanks... I have one more question. Following the second case and what you're saying, if I have all supermans with the same strength, is D3 going to look for another unique property if such one exist ? Or should I do something like `.data(mydata,something else, another something else`

Comment: No, but you can return a compound key, for example by concatenating 2 properties: `.data(mydata, function(d) { return d.name + "-" + d.strength })` - it will have the same effect that you are asking about.